# Get application logs from android

Tags: android, logging

I've developed an Android 2.2 application.

My client has it and he said me that there is a crash that I can't reproduce.

To log errors I'm using `android.util.Log;` and `ex.printStackTrace();` on every handled exception.

Is there a log about that error on device? How can I get those logs?

I could say my client to connect his device to PC and tell him where to look for those logs; copy them to his PC and send me by e-mail. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current case, you can ask your client to install any log reading app from Google Play, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat), and asking him to save the log during the crash and send them to you. Or if the client has asking to a computer with the SDK etc. setup on it, then you can ask him to execute `adb logcat -d > logcat.txt`. This will save the logcat in the file `logcat.txt`, which can then be mailed to you.

For future cases, I recommend that you integrate a project like [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/), which can automatically send you crash reports, along with information like device, stacktrace etc.